# MS Excel: How to open the comment list sub-window with visibility toggle checkboxes (show or hide)

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, comments, ribbon

I had open a spreadsheet with many comments in it, and somehow I conjured up a

- narrow window docked on the right edge of the spreadsheet
- containing a stack of checkboxes alongside a list of all the comments
  (listed just by occurrence number, e.g. something like "Comment 120")
- where the checkboxes for the comments that were hidden (the default
  for comment) were unchecked, and the checkboxes for the comments that
  were set to 'show' were checked, and the visibility of any comment
  could be changed with a checkbox change.

I thought "that's interesting", played with it a bit, then clicked the little 'x' button.

Five minutes later I thought "I want to use that window!"...but *could not figure out how to bring it up no matter how much I searched the ribbon and the ribbon customization options*!!

I don't even remember if I originally did something in the ribbon or accidentally hit some kind of keyboard shortcut.  This is was yesterday and it's already a deep mystery to me...

Help, please.

In case it matters, I'm using MS Office Professional Plus 2010.

Comment: So you want to selectively show/hide specific Comments based on checkboxes??  It would be easy if you used small textboxes rather than Comments.

Comment: I'm not sure it could be any easier than the feature I saw.  I already use comments, and again, what I am trying to re-find is a built-in part of Excel that provides a comment list with a checkbox to show or hide for each comment.

Comment: I also would be interested in the answer.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Would upvoting the question put it in front of more potential answerers?  ;)  Serious question actually.  It would impact 'hotness', wouldn't it?